# How can I install a new internal nonbearing concrete block wall in basement to partition off for bathroom?

Tags: concrete-block

house is built of concrete blocks, so basement floor is poured concrete and ceiling also. Want to know how to secure wall being built to ceiling and not having wall collapse

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to frame with lumber?

Comment: Like @DMoore says, build a wood frame partition wall. Seems kind of crazy to go through the trouble with block and mortar.

Comment: There is no reason to build a concrete block wall just as a partition wall. The rest of the walls in your basement are made out of concrete because they have to be (since they support your entire house). You can build a wall out of wood since it is an interior partition wall. You would just want to take precautions such as installing a sill gasket to prevent the frame from rotting, and using drywall that is moisture resistant.

Answer (score 1):

Load bearing or not, a concrete block wall needs a footing beyond what your questionably thick slab is.

That is why it might fall down, aside from not using [tie-ins](https://www.google.com/search?q=masonry%20tie%20ins&biw=1280&bih=890&tbm=isch&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=QGYXVfmtF8u6ggS3uoK4CA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#tbm=isch&q=metal%20masonry%20tie%20ins). AFAIK, you shouldn't have to tie-in at the ceiling, just to the side walls. I'd hope any professional would be talking about (a) pouring a footing (b) drilling holes everywhere for rebar and (c) making pockets for tie-ins. But it's a bathroom; not a vault. No one does this if they can just frame out the wall with lumber.

Ad hoc masonry must be **tied-in** to the existing structure:

[image]

([diyadvice.com](http://www.diyadvice.com/diy/patios-walls/masonry/brick-veneer-house-wall/))

[image]

([waybuilder.net](http://www.waybuilder.net/free-ed/Resources/Trades/Construction/ConcreteMasonry/default.asp?uNum=1&iNum=0802))

Answer (score 0):

You would place the wall like any other block wall.

1. get your layout
2. mix mortar
3. lay mortar on the ground (bed joint)
4. place first course of block, with mortar on ends (head joint) of block
5. place mortar between block and wall
6. lay mortar bed joint for next course, offsetting block by 1 cell (half a block)
7. repeat 4, 5, 6 until ceiling
8. strike (smooth) joint lines with a striking tool (or rounded edge of a tool handle)
9. wipe the blocks down with a wet sponge (to keep it clean)
10. wait ~1-2 weeks for mortar to cure then primer and paint

For the half **blocks** against the wall, you can **cut** them **with a circular saw with a masonry blade**. Alternatively you can score them with a chisel and hammer (messier). For the ceiling, depending on height, you will either end up just mudding the top of the last course of blocks or end up cutting the vertical height of the block first then mudding the top. When making your **mortar don't make it soupy** or it will just run out of the joints, **should be a workable mix** with minimal slump. If it's too dry, just mix a *little* water to make workable When **making bed and head joints use about a fingers distance** between blocks. To keep the  blocks level you can use a sting line or a 4 ft. level

This isn't that difficult of a task, a extra set of hands doesn't hurt either. Take your time, draw up a plan, review it, adjust as necessary, acquire materials and tools, and get dirty:) Happy Building